# Trouble accessing live server in GitHub Codespaces: Errors transitioning from 127.0.0.1 to 172.16.5.4

Tags: liveserver, github-codespaces

While using GitHub Codespaces, initially encountered an error with `127.0.0.1` when attempting to access the live server. In an attempt to resolve this, I switched to using the local IP but now receive the error

> 172.16.5.4 took too long to respond

First, I tried to address the issue by setting it to the local IP. However, this transition resulted in the new `172.16.5.4` error, persisting when trying to access the live server.